# Learning to use namespaces and modules in Javascript

Tags: javascript, module, namespaces

So, I have an example in jsfiddle that I need some help with. I have a form in html, and data that I would like to populate it with. I have encased the logic to do this in a namespace definition which I think is correct, but JsHint does not think it is and yes, my data is not being rendered in the form controls. I would appreciate some help getting this resolved please. Absolutely no Jquery is to be used as I am using only the Ext.js lib for this. Thanks in advance.

[JSFiddle link to my example][1]

```
 var data = {
        Tasks = [{
            "taskid": 1,
                "author": "Bill Maher",
                "description": "Purple Rain purple",
                "dateCreated": "12/23/2013",
                "dataModified": "2/23/2013",
                "dueDate": "2/30/2014",
                "status": "in progress"
        }, {
            "taskid": 2,
                "author": "Seth Green",
                "description": "I am not certain this is needed",
                "dateCreated": "3/24/2011",
                "dataModified": "",
                "dueDate": "5/3/2011",
                "status": "completed"
        }, {
            "taskid": 3,
                "author": "Arnold Schwatsheneggar",
                "description": "I would of course like to have data to test with",
                "dataModified": "",
                "dueDate": "",
                "status": "in progress"
        }, {
            "taskid": 4,
                "author": "Lilly blue",
                "description": "make the sun shine high again",
                "dateCreated": "4/12/2014",
                "dataModified": "",
                "dueDate": "5/10/2014",
                "status": "started"
        }, {
            "taskid": 5,
                "author": "Sam Raj",
                "description": " when will I see you again",
                "dateCreated": "",
                "dataModified": "",
                "dueDate": "",
                "status": "in progress"
        }, {
            "taskid": 6,
                "author": "Kate Kurtmann",
                "description": "Show me that you love me. See ya!",
                "dateCreated": "",
                "dataModified": "",
                "dueDate": "",
                "status": "in progress"
        }, {
            "taskid": 7,
                "author": "Kristen BenBazza",
                "description": "I am a real American",
                "dateCreated": "3/4/2013",
                "dataModified": "12/3/14",
                "dueDate": "5/23/2014",
                "status": "in progress"
        }, {
            "taskid": 8,
                "author": "Venkat Shack",
                "description": "You are the bravest of hearts, you are the strongest of souls",
                "dateCreated": "12/1/2001",
                "dataModified": "12/12/2003",
                "dueDate": "7/6/2003",
                "status": "started"
        }, {
            "taskid": 9,
                "author": "Sunny Chan",
                "description": "WHat the f is FADs anyway",
                "dateCreated": "12/1/2011",
                "dataModified": "3/12/2013",
                "dueDate": "10/10/2014",
                "status": "completed"
        }, {
            "taskid": 10,
                "author": "William Rolloff",
                "description": "Accounting for the costs improving care",
                "dateCreated": "2/12/2013",
                "dataModified": "12/01/2014",
                "dueDate": "10/15/2015",
                "status": "completed"
        }, {
            "taskid": 11,
                "author": "Aakash Khandari",
                "description": "Making a move to a better life and career",
                "dateCreated": "4/3/2000",
                "dataModified": "4/7/2005",
                "dueDate": "7/17/2014",
                "status": "in progress"
        }

        ]
    };

// more code goes here but has been deleted for brevity

   //revealing public API
    return {
        exporter.tracy: {//namespace definition 
            data = data,
            trainingTask: {//second namespace
                add = addTask,
                update = UpdateTask,
                load = loadDetail,
                clearDetail = clearForm,
                save = SubmitTask,
                remove = deleteRecord,
                expandGroup = groupexpand,
                collapseGroup = groupcollapse,
                toggleGroup = toggleGroup,
                fillMenu = fillMenu,
                setGroupStyle = setGroupStyle,
                isGrouped = isGrouped
            };
        };
    };
};
/*ending of the module*/
}(this)); //close tracy.trainingtask
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring and defining `TaskSetJson` inside a closure (the self-executed anonymous function), which is correct to modularize your code.

But you're forgetting to expose it.

You can use the RMP (Revealing Module Pattern), like this:

```
tracy = (function() {
  var foo = function(a,b,c) { ... };
  var var = function(e,f,g) { ... };
  var private_value = 1;
  var public_value = 2;
  // "Reveal" the public parts of your module
  return {
    foo: foo,
    var: var,
    public_value: public_value
  };
})();
```

With this pattern your variables and functions are declared inside a closure (the anonymous function). So, they're available for use only inside that closure. But you can make them available outside the closure by returning them.

If you want to extend an existing global variable where you're holding your var, instead of returning the revealed part of your module, you can pass it to your self-executing function, and append directly to it:

```
(function(tracy) {
  var foo = function(a,b,c) { ... };
  var var = function(e,f,g) { ... };
  var private_value = 1;
  var public_value = 2;
  // "Reveal" the public parts of your module
  tracy = {
    foo: foo,
    var: var,
    public_value: public_value
  };
})();
```

The two examples are a bit different, but in both cases you can call `tracy.foo`, `tracy.var`, or access to `tracy.public_value`.

The first example is much more flexible because you can get several indepentend instances of your module, and store them in different variables.

Comment: I think I see what you mean. BUt I have a couple of questions. Why didn't you close the first brace in the end? I mean I see right after the return statement, an open brace, and then a close brace for it but I do not see a close brace for the first brace in the statement.

Comment: I wrote it by heart... it was a typo. I've corrected it. This is one question. The second one?

Comment: so, I constructed a namespace sample using the method you have above, combining a bit of the method described in the example below. However, I seem to have problems at the return call. Please see my update above.

Comment: Pay attention to the code. You need to assign the module to your var (tracy) in any way. That doesn't happend magically. Please, look the second sample, and compare it to your code.

Answer (score 0):

`var` declares a variable optionally initialising it to a value. Quoting [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var):

> The scope of a variable declared with var is its current execution context, which is either the enclosing function or, for variables declared outside any function, global.

In your jsfiddle it seems you are expecting to have access to a variable defined inside a function but that's not possible.

I was going to fork your fiddle but it is huge. Here is an small example of using "namespaces", keep in mind the purpose of this is **to not pollute the global scope**:

```
(function(export) {

  var some_private_variable;
  var some_other_private_variable;

  function loadDetail () {

  }

  var taskSet = [{
    //a task  
  }];


  export.Tracy = {
    trainingTask: {
      load: loadDetail,
      add: addTask
    },
    TaskSet: taskSet
  };

})(this);
```

Since `this` is the global object (window) when this is executed, `export` is the window object. So you can latter use this as follow:

```
 Tracy.trainingTask.load(..)
```

Comment: On the subject of 'export', would you not then need to declare export somewhere to indicate that it is the global object? Or is that why you have this passed to the function in the end?

Comment: Also, I tried this approach but JsHint complained particularly about the section  export.Tracy = {
    trainingTask = {
      load: loadDetail,
      add: addTask
    },
    TaskSet = taskSet
  };

Comment: "expected an identifier but instead saw "export"

Comment: Any idea what this means please?

Comment: export is the parameter of the function... and I call the function with "this". Also fixed the error you found with JsHint.